# Return value by column name in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in the following format

```
ID 01 02 03 04 05 ID2 
1   1 NA NA NA NA 01
2   NA 2 NA 3  NA 04
3   NA NA 3 NA 1  05
```

Now i want to return the value in each row by ID2

for example in row 1 i want to return value 1 ,row 2 value 3 and so on based on the entries in the column ID2

```
ID Value
1   1
2   3
3   1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the "ID2" column numeric/integer or something else, i.e. factor or character?

Comment: It was a factor but i have changed it to numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cbind(df[, "ID", drop = FALSE], Value = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$ID2+1)])
#  ID Value
#1  1     1
#2  2     3
#3  3     1
```

---

- `df[, "ID", drop = FALSE]` selects the first column ("ID") and keeps it as a `data.frame`
- `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$ID2+1)]` uses subsetting to get the rows 1:3 and columns according to column "ID2" +1 because the first column is not counted
- `cbind`ing the results returns a new `data.frame`.

---

*Edit after comment:*

If you have a modified example data set like the following, where column `ID2` is `factor` and column `03` is missing:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, check.names = F, text = "
ID 01 02 03 04 05 ID2 
 1   1 NA NA NA NA 01
 2   NA 2 NA 3  NA 04
 3   NA NA 3 NA 1  05", colClasses = c(rep("integer", 6), "factor")) # read data

df$`03`<- NULL  # remove column 03
```

In this case you could modify the solution using `match`:

```
cbind(df[, "ID", drop = FALSE], Value = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$ID2, names(df)))])
#  ID Value
#1  1     1
#2  2     3
#3  3     1
```

Comment: your solution is better than mine! I like the `drop=F`, very interesting!

Comment: i have an different dimension to the questions imagine your column names are not sequential that is  ID,01,02,04,05,ID2 in which 03 is missing the above solution will throw subscript out of bounds error. can you try this scenario to come up with a solution?

Comment: @Gughan, I don't get an error if I remove column "03" and then use my proposed solution because it selects the columns by their positions. Do you mean you want to take the values in "ID2" as column names and not as column indices?

Comment: @Gughan, see my updated answer, is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
data.frame(ID=df$ID,Value=(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) df[x,df$ID2[x]+1])))

  ID Value
1  1     1
2  2     3
3  3     1
```

data:

```
df<-read.table(text="ID 01 02 03 04 05 ID2 
                     1   1 NA NA NA NA 01
                     2   NA 2 NA 3  NA 04
                     3   NA NA 3 NA 1  05",head=T)
```